# How the flip animation works in swift 2

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, swift2

I have a `UIView`, inside this view I have `UIImageView`. Also I have a button inside this `UIView`. What I want to do is when I click this button I want to make a flip animation and remove my `UIImageView` and load another view into this super view. In my button click even I did something like this

```
func shareClick()
{
    print("SHARE CLICK")
    if showingBack {

        UIView.transitionWithView(shareView, duration: 1.0, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
            self.imgVwTop.removeFromSuperview()
            }, completion: nil)

        showingBack=false

    }

    else
    {
        UIView.transitionWithView(imgVwTop, duration: 1.0, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
            self.shareView.removeFromSuperview()
            }, completion: nil)

        showingBack=true

    }


}
```

I'm confused with the ebhaviour and don't understand exactly how to do it. This button click event doing nothing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following (I assume that `share view` contains the image view and the button):

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    shareView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(30, 100, 300, 400)) //set the frame of the holder view
    flippedView = UIView(frame: shareView!.bounds)  //setup flipped view
    flippedView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor() //for test

    isFlipped = false //initially not flipped

    //set up the initial view with image and button
    aImageView = UIImageView(frame: shareView!.bounds)
    aImageView!.image = UIImage(named: "1.jpg")
    shareButton = UIButton(type: .System)
    shareButton!.setTitle("share", forState: .Normal)
    shareButton!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 50)
    shareButton!.addTarget(self, action: "shareButtonAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    //add both imageview and button to holder view
    shareView!.addSubview(aImageView!)
    shareView!.addSubview(shareButton!)

    //finally add holder to self view
    self.view.addSubview(shareView!)
}
```

Here, you can't remove the super view of the image view if you use the `transitionWithView` method. The best you can do is replace the image view with new view that you want to show after being flipped. Once again, you can flip back to the image view by adding it as subview. For example:

```
func shareButtonAction()
{
    if (self.isFlipped! == false)
    {
       UIView.transitionWithView(shareView!, duration: 0.5, options:.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: { () -> Void in
          // self.aImageView!.image = UIImage(named: "2.jpg")
         //hear remove the imageview add new view, say flipped view
          self.aImageView!.removeFromSuperview()
          self.shareView!.addSubview(self.flippedView!)
        }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
            self.isFlipped! = true
            self.shareView!.bringSubviewToFront(self.shareButton!) //button should be top of the holder view
       })
    }
    else
    {
        UIView.transitionWithView(shareView!, duration: 0.5, options:.TransitionFlipFromRight, animations: { () -> Void in
            //move back, remove flipped view and add the image view
            self.flippedView!.removeFromSuperview()
            self.shareView!.addSubview(self.aImageView!)
            }, completion: { (Bool) -> Void in
                self.isFlipped! = false
                self.shareView!.bringSubviewToFront(self.shareButton!)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you have the right idea, I believe you have things set up correctly with the view you want to flip in some sort of container.

I think it would help if you instantiated both your views programmatically, in your case a UIImageView and a Button. When you transition the other view will become unloaded because they are listed as weak so best to create them on the fly.

I made up a view controller to test the idea, initially the currentView will be instantiated from the storyboard, and then after that would be created programmatically, every time the button is pressed it will create a new view that will replace the other, perform the animation and set the new view as the currentView for the next time the button is pressed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var currentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
    var flipped = false

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let new: UIView!

        if flipped {
            new = UIImageView(frame: container.bounds)
            new.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            flipped = false
        }
        else {
            new = UIButton(frame: container.bounds)
            new.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            flipped = true
        }


        let options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.TransitionFlipFromLeft, .AllowUserInteraction, .BeginFromCurrentState]
        UIView.transitionFromView(currentView, toView: new, duration: 0.5, options: options, completion: nil)
        self.currentView = new

    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code works...

```
   self.debug.hidden = true
   let image = UIImage(data: data!)
   self.debug.image = image

   if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left) {
                            UIView.transitionWithView(self.debug, duration: 1.0, options: [.TransitionFlipFromRight], animations: {
                                self.debug.hidden = false
                                }, completion: { _ in })
                        }
```

I load a new image into my image after I hide it.